# Why is the HTTP response not giving me my specified range of data?

Tags: java, networking, http-headers, range, httpresponse

So I am grabbing an HTTP object such as a .png from a url using the Range property. I find the content-length of the whole object and then I split up the starting bytes and ending bytes of each range. Everything works fine up until the last range.

```
// My specified range is:
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=22128-27657");

// It returns (Response Header):
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Thu, 17 Mar 2016 17:04:34 GMT
Downloaded Size: 5533
bytes
5529
bytes 22128-27656/27657 // !!! - Incorrect
Keep-Alive
```

However, on every other range, I am getting the data I ask for:

```
// My specified range is:
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=5533-11066");

// It returns (Response Header):
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Thu, 17 Mar 2016 17:04:34 GMT
Downloaded Size: 5533
bytes
5529
bytes 5533-11066/27657 // !!! - Correct
Keep-Alive
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte ranges are 0-indexed. With `bytes=22128-27657`, you're asking for the 22129th byte through the 27658th byte, but there are only 27657 bytes. Both of your examples are behaving correctly.

Comment: So I am getting all of the data?

Comment: Correct. `22128-27656/27657` means that all remaining data from position `22128` to the end of the document was returned.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the [`Content-Range`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.2) header is defined as (abbreviated):

```
 Content-Range       = byte-content-range
 byte-content-range  = bytes-unit SP byte-range-resp
 byte-range-resp     = byte-range "/" ( complete-length / "*" )
 byte-range          = first-byte-pos "-" last-byte-pos
 complete-length     = 1*DIGIT
```

and [section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-2.1) says:

```
 first-byte-pos      = 1*DIGIT
 last-byte-pos       = 1*DIGIT
```

> The first-byte-pos value in a byte-range-spec gives the byte-offset
> of the first byte in a range.  The last-byte-pos value gives the
> byte-offset of the last byte in the range; that is, **the byte
> positions specified are inclusive**.  **Byte offsets start at zero.**

So with a length of `27657`, positions are `0-27656`.

When you ask for `22128-27657`, you are asking for more bytes than are available, and the response is truncated to what is actually available.